# Automapper Unable to cast object of type 'Parent' to type 'Child'

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes Base short class

```
 public class ObjectShortEditView
 {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

full view

```
public class ObjectEditView : ObjectShortEditView
 {
        public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

in automapper profile

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ObjectShortEditView>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ObjectEditView >().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

IgnoreAllNonExistingExtension

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>
            (this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
        {
            var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
            var destinationProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties(flags);

            foreach (var property in destinationProperties)
            {
                if (sourceType.GetProperty(property.Name, flags) == null)
                {
                    expression.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
                }
            }
            return expression;
        }
```

Problem is when i try to map from entity to full edit view it fails

```
var view = Mapper.Map<ObjectEditView>(entityFromDb);
```

And some times it fails with exception

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ObjectShortEditView' to type 'ObjectEditView '.
```

Mean while i wrote this i got idea that it could be ignore all extension but why it even try to cast to short view when i ask map me to full view...

Comment: You could implement an interface in both your parent and child classes.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer yes its what i think to do and thanks now will move to that for sure since it will fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using AutoMapper Version 4? Maybe even in combination with EF 6.x?

It looks like this might be related to your topic then: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/842

One statement is then: "Please consider downgrade to AutoMapper 3.3.1"

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat We are currently on AutoMapper 3.x too, I had several difficulties with mapping my Entities when trying to upgrade to 4. With some nested objects, it even resulted in StackOverflowExceptions. With 3.x we're pretty save.

Comment: yes because same works before firstly i thought is my fault somewhere but i see, will downgrade it ...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try your scenario, but there is a `.Include<>` Syntax to help with Inheritance topics. You would declare it like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ObjectShortEditView>()
    .Include<Entity, ObjectEditView>()
    .IgnoreAllNonExisting();
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ObjectEditView>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

Maybe this could resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes i tried that even tried with includebase but same problem

Comment: Include is more when you bind from various types orderbase, order to viewbase, view